# Require if in where condition SQL

Tags: sql

I want to fetch the data based on the key_column in the table. I am having a procedure where i am passing the key character. If the key is 'A' only those records with key as 'A' should get selected . For any other key character other than 'A', I need all the records except the rows with the key_Column value 'A'

sample code:

```
select * from tab1
where 
if (@key_Char = 'A') Then key_Column=@key_Char 
ELSE key_Column <>@key_Char
```

Comment: Not all SQL products support this (hence putting it in a comment): `WHERE (key_column = 'A') = (@key_char = 'A')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
select * from tab1
where (@key_Char = 'A' AND key_Column='A') OR
      (@key_Char <> 'A' AND key_Column <> 'A')
```

Comment: I edited this while it was deleted, hope that's OK. I see you undeleted it at the same time. I think a `XOR` would work nicely here, if it is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
WHERE (@key_char = 'A' AND  key_column = 'A') OR (@key_char <>'A' AND key_column <>'A')
```

Comment: Sorry, redundant answer, took too long to edit with android tab :(